# Accessing data object form derived class from friend Base class

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am trying out an implementation of Policy based design as below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using uint =  unsigned int ;
struct hashing_scheme_base_v;
template <typename T=int,typename hashing_scheme_t=hashing_scheme_base_v>
struct hash_map;

struct hashing_scheme_base_v
{
    virtual void allocate(uint value) = 0;
};
struct hashing_scheme_der:public hashing_scheme_base_v
{
    template <typename T,typename hashing_scheme_t>
    void allocate(uint value)
    {
        typedef typename hash_map<T,hashing_scheme_t>::data hash_map_data;
        hash_map_data[value % hash_map_data.size()] = value;
    }
};
template <typename T,typename hashing_scheme_t>
struct hash_map: public hashing_scheme_t
{
    std::vector <T> data;
    hash_map(int size)
    {
        data = std::vector <T> (size,-1);
    }
    friend struct hashing_scheme_der;
};
int main()
{
    hash_map <int,hashing_scheme_der> m_hmap(10);
    return 0;
}
```

And I got the following error

```
**: In member function 'void hashing_scheme_der::allocate(uint)':
../kaufmann/ADTs/divide_and_conquer.cpp:18:28: error: expected ']' before '%' token
   18 |         hash_map_data[value % hash_map_data.size()] = value;
      |                            ^~
      |                            ]
../kaufmann/ADTs/divide_and_conquer.cpp:18:22: error: structured binding declaration cannot have type 'hash_map_data'
   18 |         hash_map_data[value % hash_map_data.size()] = value;
      |                      ^
../kaufmann/ADTs/divide_and_conquer.cpp:18:22: note: type must be cv-qualified 'auto' or reference to cv-qualified 'auto'
../kaufmann/ADTs/divide_and_conquer.cpp:18:51: error: declaration of 'auto value' shadows a parameter
   18 |         hash_map_data[value % hash_map_data.size()] = value;
      |                                                   ^
../kaufmann/ADTs/divide_and_conquer.cpp: In function 'int main()':
../kaufmann/ADTs/divide_and_conquer.cpp:33:39: error: cannot declare variable 'm_hmap' to be of abstract type 'hash_map<int, hashing_scheme_der>'
   33 |     hash_map <int,hashing_scheme_der> m_hmap(10);
      |                                       ^~~~~~
../kaufmann/ADTs/divide_and_conquer.cpp:22:8: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'hash_map<int, hashing_scheme_der>':
   22 | struct hash_map: public hashing_scheme_t
      |        ^~~~~~~~
../kaufmann/ADTs/divide_and_conquer.cpp:10:18: note:    'virtual void hashing_scheme_base_v::allocate(uint)'
   10 |     virtual void allocate(uint value) = 0;
      |                  ^~~~~~~~
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.**
```

How do I forward declare the base classes to resolve the compile errors I am getting?

Many Thanks!

Edit::

I resolved the error,the design was faulty to begin with. Here's the corrected code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using uint =  unsigned int ;

template<typename Derived>
struct hashing_scheme_base_v;

template<typename DataType,typename Derived>
struct removal_scheme_base_v;
/*
template <typename T=int,template <typename > typename hashing_scheme_t=hashing_scheme_base_v>
struct hash_map;*/

template <typename T,template <typename > typename hashing_scheme_t,template <typename ...> typename removal_scheme_t >
struct hash_map;

template<typename Derived>
struct hashing_scheme_base_v
{
    virtual void allocate(uint value) = 0;
};
template<typename Derived>
struct hashing_scheme_der:public hashing_scheme_base_v <Derived>
{
    void allocate(uint value)
    {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->data[value%static_cast<Derived*>(this)->data.size()] = value;
    }

};
// Removal scheme
template<typename DataType,typename Derived>
struct removal_scheme_base_v
{
    virtual void remove(DataType value) = 0;
};
template<typename DataType,typename Derived>
struct removal_scheme_der:public removal_scheme_base_v <DataType,Derived>
{
    void remove(DataType value)
    {
        if(static_cast<Derived*>(this)->data[value%static_cast<Derived*>(this)->data.size()] == value)
            static_cast<Derived*>(this)->data[value%static_cast<Derived*>(this)->data.size()] = -1;
    }

};
template <typename T,template <typename > typename hashing_scheme_t,template <typename... > typename removal_scheme_t >
struct hash_map: public hashing_scheme_t<hash_map <T,hashing_scheme_t,removal_scheme_t>>,removal_scheme_t<T,hash_map <T,hashing_scheme_t,removal_scheme_t>>
{
    std::vector <T> data;
    hash_map(int size)
    {
        data = std::vector <T> (size,-1);
    }
    inline void print()
    {
        for(auto itr:data)
        {
            std::cout<<itr<<" ";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    hash_map <int,hashing_scheme_der,removal_scheme_der> m_hmap(10);
    m_hmap.allocate(3.00);
    m_hmap.allocate(5.00);
    m_hmap.allocate(17.00);
    m_hmap.print();
    m_hmap.remove(17.00);
    m_hmap.print();
    return 0;
}
```

The above code uses CRTP to access derived class objects in the Base Class,this allows us to use the hash_map class just as an object which holds data and containers and base classes implment the functionality

Comment: The two lines in `allocate()` don't make sense. You are trying to access `data` member of `hash_map`, but you don't have any `hash_map` to work with. It looks like you added `typedef` and `typename` randomly to fix a compiler error, because then you use a type as if it was an object. Forward declaring will not fix anything, this code is fundamentally broken.

Comment: Hi @Yksisarvinen
 I am still new to Policy based design, forgive me for this basic error, could you please suggest a remedy?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see any way to fix this code. Looking at all the strange pieces of code all around it just seems that this task is beyond your current capabilities. You don't know enough about templates to work this out. I'm not sure if learning templates is reasonable at your level, but I'd suggest starting small, maybe with reimplementing `std::vector` or `std::array`, then move on to `hash_map` (with single "policy") and only after that to `hash_map` with different policies. [A good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) will be helpful

Comment: I see, I resolved the error, and you were right. The design was wrong to begin with, I added CRTP and that seemed to correct the error.